# Java: Writing to a log file from a server

Tags: java, file-io

Im trying to create a log file for a small chatroom I've created.
so far this is what I have for the logging:

```
static void log(String s){
    try{
        BufferedWriter writer =
                new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("log"+getTime()+".txt"));
        writer.write(s);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I call it in this way in a thread for each connection each time I brodcast to the clients:

```
log(name+"String")
```

but after its called and doesn't continue the program. however, when this did work, the only thing in the text file would be one line, the first one called. how can one fix both these bugs?

Comment: You have more than one problem with your code; for instance you don't close the log file, you don't specify the encoding, you open one descriptor per write...

Comment: @fge please explain how could these problems be solved, I can close it, but when I do, only the first thing written stays in the file. I don't know how to specify encoding? also, I do not understand what having one descriptor means

Comment: Before an explanation can be given, what is the intent? What is `.getTime()` here?

Comment: @KEYSER so, I want to `.close()` once the server is being shut down, but could you give an example to how to change the descriptor problem

Comment: @fge `.get(Time)` purely returns a string showing the date in this format: `"yyyy"+"-"+"MM"+"-"+"dd"+"-"+"HH"+"-"+"mm"+"-"+"ss"`
the purpose is to have chat logs for a small socket based server-client chat program I'm coding

Comment: Well, you want to do it like this: open-write-close. More or less. Close the file as soon as you're done writing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the other answers, you don't close the file and you are not writing a line separator.

I see that there's one perfect answer in Java 7, but you said in the comments that you are not able to use that. (I suppose you are using Java 6 instead)

Because of that, I have written an implementation using only Java 6 API (using the Java 6 javadocs for reference):

```java
public class LogFileHelper {
  private final BufferedWriter writer;

  public LogFileHelper(File outputFile) throws IOException {
    if(!outputFile.exists()){ //The JavaDoc says that it is not certain if the file will be created
      outputFile.createNewFile();
    }

    this.writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true));
  }

  public void writeLine(String line) throws IOException {
    if(line == null){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("line may not be null");
    }

    this.writer.write(line);
    this.writer.newLine();
    this.writer.flush(); //Make sure the line we just wrote is written and kept if the application crashes
  }

  public void tryWriteLine(String line) {
    try {
      writeLine(line);
    } catch(IOException ioe){
      //Your exception handling here
    }
  }

  public void close() throws IOException {
    this.writer.close();
  }

  public void tryClose() {
    try {
      this.writer.close();
    } catch(IOException ioe){
      //Your exception handling here
    }
  }
}
```

I added tryXXX methods to simplify exception handling, as I suppose you will use the same everywhere. I kept the base methods to allow for custom exception handling where needed.

With above class, you would store the instance somewhere, write to it where needed and close it on exit. Your best bet for that is a shutdown handler like this one:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("Chatlog Shutdown Thread"){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    myLogFileHelper.tryClose();
  }
});
```

Where you would execute that statement just after you create your `LogFileHelper` instance.

The above code does flush every time you write something - If you want to go super efficient, you could flush less often. A valid use case for not flushing immediately would be when writing a whole batch of lines at once, although you always have to balance between not flushing and having the file on disk immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Use try-with-resources and write in *append mode*:

```
static void log(String s) {
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new FileWriter("log" + getTime() + ".txt", true)))) {
        out.println(s);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to output anything whatsoever, only create the file.

Comment: If you use Java 7 why not go all the way and use `Files.newBufferedWriter` instead?

Comment: @user3555902 Works flawlessly, tested it!

Comment: @DenisKulagin in the way I seem to be calling, it doesn't work, this may be due to it not being closed, but above I am trying to get an explanation on how to do such a thing

Comment: Try-with-resources block closes the stream. Please, try to output some static data (e.g. "123" and not *s*). Then check, if it works.

Comment: @DenisKulagin I tried static data (exactly `"123"` in fact) and it still only created blank files

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems:

- each time you log *one statement* you open a new file descriptor;
- ... which you don't close;
- given on the output of `.getTime()` you may even write to several different files.

Use a dedicated class which you initialize and share *once* across all classes which use logging facilities; for instance a singleton.

In the constructor you would open the file:

```
private final BufferedWriter writer;

// ...

public MyLogFile()
    throws IOException
{
    final Path path = Paths.get("path to logfile");
    writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}
```

Use a method to write a line:

```
public void writeOneLine(@Nonnull final String line)
    throws IOException
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(line, "won't write null, sorry");
    writer.write(line);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.flush();
}
```

As for closing the file when you exit, either make you class implement `Closeable` and `.close()` it when your program ends (or even `AutoCloseable`) or add a JVM shutdown hook.

Comment: Eclipse is stating that some of these variables or types are resolveable:
`Path`,`Paths`,`Files` all of the variables beggining with `Standard`
as well as `.writeLine()` and `Objects`

Comment: Hmm, aren't you using Java 7?